# Which one would represent complete combustion?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, thermal-conductivity

Say that I want to burn some fuel, so I'm aiming for a complete combustion, hence CO = 0

So I have 2 possibilities

a) CO2 quantity = maximum, CO quantity = 0 (complete combustion) and O2 quantity = maximum (21%)

or

b)  CO2 quantity = maximum, CO quantity = 0 (complete combustion) and O2 quantity = 0

which one would make more sense for a complete combustion?

Comment: Where did the oxygen for the combustion come from in case a)?

Comment: @noah I'm trying to have a complete combustion within a oven at like 1000 degrees C or so.

Comment: Though that at a) Oxygen = 21% would indicate levels close to the atmosphere...I find it hard to believe that so much oxygen can get into a combustion chamber

Comment: I guess that a) would be valid just if the complete combustion would happen within the open atmosphere. So I guess b) seems the correct answer...

Answer (score 2):

> which one would make more sense for a complete combustion?

Neither, really. You can't verify whether a combustion is 'complete' or not, without stoichiometry.

But first we need to define 'complete'. In chemical terms this means that all the constituent chemical elements of the fuel have reached their highest possible **oxidation state**, post-combustion.

Take a generic fuel $\text{C}_x\text{H}_y$ and its complete combustion reaction:

$$\text{C}_x\text{H}_y+\Big(x+\frac{y}{4}\Big)\text{O}_2\to x\text{CO}_2+\frac{y}{2}\text{H}_2\text{O}$$

This stoichiometry tells you how many mol (or $\mathrm{kg}$) of $\text{O}_2$ is needed for each mol (or $\mathrm{kg}$) of fuel, to reach the highest possible oxidation states ($+4$ for carbon, $+1$ for hydrogen, $-2$ for oxygen)

The presence of $\text{CO}$ in the combustion products would mean the combustion is incomplete because the oxidation state of carbon in $\text{CO}$ is only $+2$.